# Android Studio 2.1: Getting users latitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps

I know this question is a repeated question, but i didn't find a clear answer. I am using Studio 2.1 and I need below information:

I am developing a app, which gets the latitude and logitude from one mobile and send those details to Master/Server Mobile, so that server mobile will show the tracking maps on server mobile.

Here i need an over all process.
 1. I developed a background code in client mobile

After 1st step, i am confused how to move further. Do I need to create any website and capture the latitude and longitude.

OR

Do i need to follow any other steps.

Please guide me only on higher level steps.

Comment: it's up to you to choose how your server and client mobile device will communicate. there are many options available depending on your needs :bluethoot,wifi,sockets,server side api, etc

Answer (score 0):

Look into **LocationManager** and **FusedLocationProvider** apis. As for sending locations, both these provide callbacks when they find the location, and they do this at regular intervals which you can specify

```
onLocationChanged()
```

Here you can call your own logic to send the found coordinates to a master, maybe via a web service, cloud ... etc. There are many ways and what suits your needs is upto you.

You can set your own provider in case of LocationManager i.e GPS, NETWORK ...

In FusedLocation ,it does this on its own.

Both have their own perks. Use which ever suits your needs.